# Disassembling Hexagon - Corrupted ELF

Tags: ida, firmware, elf, file-format

I downloaded and unpacked the modem from Google source, after that
I used laginimaineb's script to unify all modem binary data. However, when loading this binary to IDA, I get an error says:

> ```
> Binary data is incorrect, maximum possible value is xxxxxx
> ```

I tried to do the same thing by pulling this modem.b* from the device itself. The same behavior.

I opened up this binary into 010 Editor and check the section size, and it seems like the sections have a size bigger than the binary size.

How could I fix the binary? Assuming that the first sections are valid, could I use that information to calculate the further section sizes?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you used  [this script](https://github.com/laginimaineb/unify_trustlet) during your research. Please note the script is Little Endian architecture oriented. Can you double check endianness in your examples?